# Key image forgery

Tags: ringct

Given a keypair (k,K); the key image is calculated as:

KeyImage = k * H(K)

What is stopping someone from giving a fake `K` in the hash function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Schnorr signature construction that is part of the ring signature ensures that the signer of the MLSAG knows the private key `k` of the public key `k*H(K)`. That part of the signature is verified in the usual way except using the alternate base point `H(K)` instead of the usual `G`.

The verifier is the one that calculates that base point `H(K)` themselves during verification. So although the specified key image may be falsified, a falsified key image would not verify during the `r*H(K) + c*keyimage` step, because the falsifier controls the key image but not the `H(K)` point that is  used in the `r*H(K)` part of the verification.

It's not mathematically possible for the signer to come up with a value of `r` that will successfully verify unless at the verification time the point `H(K)` is a common factor of both `r*H(K)` and `c*keyimage`.